# Better volume adjustment for headphones

Tags: windows-7, headphones

I have wired headphones (3,5mm) which I have connected to my computer. The problem is that I have to set 2-3% in the speakers control to get a decent volume (way too loud otherwise). Even that is too loud sometimes.

Get I fix the volume control in some way? It's hard to adjust it since small adjustments makes large differences.

[image: My normal volume]

**Edit**: I just tried to plugin the headphones in the front port instead. Now they show up as headphones instead of speakers. But the problem remains.

Comment: TV headphones with independent volume control. http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/private_headphones_hifi_tv-headphones_504685

Comment: @Aki: lol. Are your solution proposal that I buy new headphones?

Comment: Are they powered headphones? an Attenuating adapter or cable would reduce the signal level going to the headphones, so the system volume can be adjusted.  You can make one or an adjustable one, by just putting resistance on the 2 signal wires.   One thing to quick check in software,  in the control pannel **Sound**, in the **Playback** tab, bring up the **properties** for the Speaker/headphones, and get into the **Advanced** tab, and Un Check **[ ]Enable audio enhancments**, that is for additional filtering of the sounds.

Comment: I like those headphones, just slide the pot to fine tune "the noise level".

Comment: This is still a problem in 2015!  I wish windows let you fiddle with the gain on a finer level.  Too damn loud :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a set of external speakers connected to this machine at all, or available to plug in?

Some sets of speakers have a headphone socket on them also and, if you have a set that has one, it may give you a better signal than direct from your "line out" connections.

I have several sets of speakers for my PC's and most have a headphone socket which gives a great range of volume with my headphones.

Comment: I've tried all output sockets. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try looking at the headphone/speaker property in Playback Device ?

In the enhancement tab, see what option you have, play around with them. I can't tell you exactly as it's depend on your sound card driver. Look for something with loudness, or sound boost.

Or your can try to uninstall the sound driver then reinstall it with the latest one.

Lastly, you can try to reformat Windows.

Comment: I've tried all options in there.

Comment: can you please confirm that 1. Your headphone works well with other computer (not too loud) and 2. Problem still persist when you plug in a different headphone to your computer.

Comment: Tried different headphones. Same problem. Why would a reformat work?